# Implementing custom indexer on a collection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to make a custom indexer on a collection. Here are my classes:

Business Class:

```
public class UserCollection : Collection<User>
{
    public new User this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == index);
        }
    }

}
```

BL API Method:

```
public static Collection<User> GetUser()
{
    return new UserCollection
               {
                   new User {UserID = 2},
                   new User {UserID = 4}
               };
}
```

Usage:

```
  Collection<User> users = GetUser();
    User user = users[2];

    }
```

User class has few columns like UserID, UserName etc. I want to fetch a user from collection via index and here index will be user id. But the above usage code is not doing it, and it is  considering indexer of parent Collection class. I want my custom indexer to come into play. I can do it by exposing UserCollection as the return type of GetUser method and then the solution will be to use the code like this

```
UserCollection users = GetUser();
```

But I am thinking to return the most general type from BL method here which is Collection. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Naming your function "GetByUserId" or similar might be less confusing to callers and avoid a lot of this mess since the indexer properties are conventionally used to access the _nth_ element (when by int) or an element keyed by that value (when by string/other type).

Answer (score 5):

Read the documentation for [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132434.aspx) carefully paying close attention to the 'Notes to Inheritors' section. It will link to another page that gives you an example of doing what you're trying to do.

You might also want to check out the [`KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) class which might make things a bit easier on you. Your custom class would simply become:

```
public class UserCollection: KeyedCollection<int, User>
{

    public UserCollection() : base() {}

    protected override int GetKeyForItem(User user)
    {
        return user.UserID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want `UserCollection` to extend `Collection<User>`? Your `UserCollection` is clearly not a `Collection<User>`, since its indexing (one of the base things for a collection) is different!

I would suggest just including a `Collection<User>` as a field of `UserCollection` and accessing it in the indexer.

Answer (score 1):

You could return an ICollection rather than a Collection. That would make your indexer virtual.

```
public class UserCollection : ICollection<User>
{
    public User this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == index);
        }
    }

    // all the other ICollection methods

}

public static ICollection<User> GetUser()
{
    return new UserCollection
               {
                   new User {UserID = 2},
                   new User {UserID = 4}
               };
}
```

But I agree with Vlad, it isn't really a collection. I think it is more like a dictionary. Consider IDictionary. Or even ToDictionary() from Enumerable extensions (where you can specify your key).

Answer (score 0):

Your indexers aren't virtual methods; when you define your indexer for the subclass you're hiding the parent implementation, not overriding it, so whenever the item is cast as it's parent type it will use the parent definition of the indexer (if it has one).  If the object is cast as the child type it will use the indexer of the child (in this case, your custom one).

If `Collection` is a custom collection of yours you can define it as virtual, and use `override` rather than `new` in the child class, and then it will work as expected.  If not, you're SOL.

Comment: The Collection here is under the namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel

Comment: This is in general.  For your specific situation, the documentation for that class specifically describes how to override the functionality through overriding a protected method (see other answer by Justin).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a dictionary instead?

```
Dictionary<UserID,Users>
```

Then you could just look up the key/values by ID.